# If a person from a large company you want to work at gives you his number for a job opportunity, when should you call him back?

Tags: job-search, recruitment

If a person from a very large company that I want to work at has given me in person his number on a Friday morning (for a possible job opportunity), should I call him on that Friday afternoon (when he might not be at work already), or should I wait till Monday? Should I send him a message instead of calling?

Sorry for the weird question, I just think this stuff has an impact but I'm clueless as to how to act in such situations.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: "you're so money and you don't even know it"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call him whenever you'd like to and ask him when would be most convenient to have a discussion about the job opportunity.  So the Friday afternoon should be fine.

If the phone goes to voicemail, leave a message (and be prepared to know what you want to say in that voicemail so that you sound confident right off the bat).

There's no need here to discuss the opportunity itself immediately, the first call is just to get in touch and scheduled in something later on.  It shouldn't really take up more than 30 seconds or so of his time.